# Colorbox and ListView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview, colorbox

I am relatively new with JavaScript / jQuery, and have less than 6 months experience with ASP.NET.  I have run into a problem using the [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) plugin for an ASP.NET w/ SQL Server application.

Right now, I am using colorbox to open a larger display of a thumbnail picture in a PhotoGallery I have been developing. All seems to work fine, I can group photos together in the colorbox display.

Everything works, except my `ListView` has paging, so there is only a display of 40 images per page. Colorbox will only group the photos that are currently on the `ListView` page.

.ASPX page `ListView` (not pretty but it works)

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="padding:10px">
        <a class='colorbox' href="/Photos/AllPhotos/<%#Eval("FileName") %>" 
            title="<strong><%# Eval("Title") %></strong> photo by: <%#Eval("Name") %>">
        <img src="/Photos/AllPhotos/Thumbnail/<%#Eval("FileName") %>"
            title="<%# Eval("Title") %>" /></a>
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

JavaScript for binding colorbox:

```
function pageLoad() {
    $("a.colorbox").colorbox({
        rel: "gal",
        maxWidth: "100%",
        maxHeight: "100%"
    })
};
```

What I would like is to have colorbox bind to all photos that are bound to the `ListView`, and not just the current page. So ideally a user can page through all photos in our gallery (by clicking on one of the thumbnails) and not have to close colorbox --> go to next page --> open colorbox again.

Is there an easy way to bind the colorbox to all photos in the `ListView`?  I can think of a couple "hack" methods (such as binding photos to a hidden `ListView`, and grouping them with the displayed photos) but I am trying to develop an application that is nice to work with!

I found something that looks [promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747665/colorbox-gallery-using-json/), but I have never used JSON / SQL before, so there will be a learning curve there for me if I have to go that way.

Any help would be appreciated, I use these forums a lot at work, so this was my first place to come for advice.

(Sorry if I missed anything, this is my first post)

**EDIT**

Well I figured something out, that gets the job done, but maybe not as nicely as I had hoped. What I ended up doing was creating a second array that I populated with all the photos that were not displayed, binding that to a hidden ListView, then colorbox grouping the hidden photos with the displayed photos. It seems to work fine, just not as clean as I had hoped, so I am still open to a better method (if there is one), but for now I am content.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding, but could you just disable the paging on your `ListView`?  Or is that not what you're going for?

Comment: I could, and yes, that is the effect I am going after. But my boss is fairly adamant on having only a few on the page, while the rest can be access via clicking on a thumbnail :/

Comment: You might want to check out something like [datatables](http://datatables.net/).  Then you can bind all the data to the listview server-side, and handle all the paging client-side.  And all your colorbox links will still work great.

Comment: hmm, this looks interesting and would like to try it, but as for the execution I am a bit lost. It looks easy enough to use, I downloaded the .js file, and referenced it in the aspx page, but thats about as far as I got. Right now I am querying a SQL database, and binding the datatable it returns to the listview in the code-behind. How would I go about integrating the dataTables.js stuff? Thanks again for any help you can provide.

Comment: FYI, you can use the "@" symbol to notify people in comments (for instance @hmqcnoesy will notify the other person in this comment chain).

Comment: @MikeChester - I'll put some info in an answer, and you can mark it if it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to use [datatables](http://datatables.net/) and bind all your data to the ListView on the server (don't use paging on your ListView) and get smoother paging on the client-side, that will still work with colorbox.

Set your ListView's LayoutTemplate up.  You'll need a table with class of "datatable" and you'll also need thead and tbody for datatables to work, plus some way to select the table with jQuery (here I'm making the id "tblStuff" and making sure there is no runat="server").  Also, be careful if you created the LayoutTemplate in the design view, because Visual Studio has a habit of nesting one table inside another one.

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table id="tblStuff" class="datatable">
        <thead><tr><th>...(Your <th> elements go here)...</tr></thead>
        <tbody><tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

Now in script, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.colorbox').colorbox({
        // just how you had it before.
    });

    $('#tblStuff').dataTable({
        // here is where you'll want to set some of the many many options for datatables.
        // See their documentation.
    });
});
```

That's all there is to it.  You should be able to keep your ItemTemplate unchanged.

Comment: Hey thanks, I managed to get the datatable working, but the original problem still remains (from what I can tell). What I was trying to accomplish is having only say 20/80 pictures being displayed, and being able to open color box on one of the 20/80 pictures, then by flicking through the pictures (in colorbox) being able to see them all (the remaining 60), without actually having them all displayed on the gallery page (which are thumbnail pictures). The only way I have foudn to accomplish this is binding the remaining photos to a hidden listview. But I'll keep looking. Thanks.